# what did i do wrong (simple statistic)

Tags: c++, while-loop, c++17

**Description**

Mr. Dengklek has you N integers. Among these numbers, determine the largest and smallest numbers.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer N. The next line contains N integers.

**Output Format**

A row contains A B, where A is the largest number and B is the smallest number.

**Input Example**

8

1 -1 1 10 10 6 8 4

**Example Output**

10 -1

Limits

1 ≤ N ≤ 100

-100,000 ≤ (every integer on the second line) ≤ 100,000

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int N,A,B, temp;
  while (true)
  {
    cin >> N;
    if(N > 0 && N <= 100){
      break;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    cin >> temp;
    if(temp >= -100000 && temp <= 100000){
      if(temp < A && temp < B){
        B = temp;
      }
      else if(temp > B && temp > A){
        A = temp;
      }
    }
    else{
      i--;
    }
    
  }
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << B << endl;
  return 0;
  
  
}
```

I got WA and 0pts in this question can you help me figure out what's wrong i've been testing this program and it runs fine

Comment: `EOF` is a negative value that indicates that the reading reached at the end of input. Would you mind showing your code that is producing WA (a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: Google cpp scanf.

Comment: For solving your home work, have you had a thorough look at the "hint"? What does it do and what needs to be changed to make a parrot program? Also, with a debugger, if you break in the while loop, you see what variable gets what value.

Comment: i changed the question, sorry, i'm new here and stack overflow limits my question while i'm desperate of help

Answer (score 1):

EOF means End Of File so you should write every word contained in the array while not reach the end of input.